# SQL Server - Select Specific Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with data:

```
id  a_no  accountname
1    NULL   ac1  
1    234    ac2
1    567    ac3
2    NULL   ac4
```

I want to select row with the following criteria:

1. if same id exist in more than 1 row, then remove the row with `a_no=NULL`
2. if id exist in 1 row only, keep that row unchanged

So that the resulting rows should be

```
id  a_no  accountname
1    234    ac2
1    567    ac3
2    NULL   ac4
```

How to write the T-SQL query?  Thanks.

Comment: What if 2 NULL values exist for same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from yourtable
where a_no is not null
union all
select * from yourtable
where id not in 
    (select id from your table where a_no is not null)
```

Comment: although Martijn and Mosty write better code, Phil first answer correctly.  Thanks all guys anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM yourtable
             WHERE NOT a_no IS NULL)
AND a_no IS NULL
```

Edit: Much simpler
Edit II: Misread your question, you only want to select the rows, not delete them from your table. If so, you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable
WHERE a_no IS NOT NULL
OR id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM yourtable
              WHERE a_no IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Martinjn query I'd go for:

```
select * from t
where id not in (
  select id from t
  where a_no is not null)
or a_no is not null
```